# Akzept, Akzeption, Akzeptation, Akzeptanz?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

Ich war neugierig auf die Nomen für das Verb "akzeptieren" und fand diese:

- das **Akzept** ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzept), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Akzept))

  - Bedeutung a): *Annahmeerklärung des Bezogenen (Zahlungspflichtigen) auf einem Wechsel*
  - Bedeutung b): *akzeptierter Wechsel*
- die **Akzeption** ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeption))

  - Bedeutung: *Akzeptation*
- die **Akzeptation** ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptation), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Akzeptation))

  - Bedeutung: *Annahme (z. B. eines Wechsels), Anerkennung*
- die **Akzeptanz** ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptanz), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Akzeptanz))

  - Bedeutung: *Bereitschaft, etwas zu akzeptieren*

Ich glaube, alle oben werden auf Englisch "Acceptance" übersetzt.

**Aber was sind die Unterschiede zwischen diesen?**

(Die zweite ist die seltsamste, die konnte ich nur im Duden finden, mit der Bedeutung *gleichwertig* die dritte!)

Comment: Wo hast du diese Wörter gefunden? Bis auf "Akzeptanz" sind sie alle irgendetwas zwischen selten und seltsam. Jedenfals definitiv nicht Teil eines täglichen (auch arbeitstäglichen) Wortschatzes. Und man kann natürlich noch mehr erfinden: Akzeptierung, Akzeptifikation, Akzeptabilität (das würde ich sogar als existierend akzeptieren), Akzeptat...

Comment: PS: *Akzept* (wie auch *Akzeptor* und *Akzeptant*; alle drei in meinem Duden Universalwörterbuch) kommt wohl aus der Sprache der Kaufleute, sofern sie noch mit Wechseln (schulrechtliches Wertpapier) agieren. Aber tut man das noch?

Comment: Tatsächlich gängig im Alltag ist "Akzeptanz" und vielleicht noch die Substantivierung "das Akzeptieren".

Comment: *d* Das ist das fehlende "d" für Christians schuldrechtliches Wertpapier. Die Lebenszeit einer Vokabel ist m. E. aber nicht an die Lebenszeit des Gegenstandes gekoppelt (vergleiche *Wählscheibe*), von daher ist der Einwand wohl eher auf die zu erwartende Nutzungshäufigkeit der Vokabeln gemünzt.

Comment: @guidot wohl eher gekoppelt an die Lebenszeit der Menschen, die besagten Gegenstand noch benutzt haben.

Comment: @guidot  Vielen ank für as d! Mir sin sie grae ausgegangen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich habe eine Liste der einigen Verben mit Ihre häufige Substantiv gemacht. Ich wusste nicht welche Nomen von "akzeptieren" wird  verwendet...

Comment: Nach Einschätzung von Wikipedia spielen Wechsel im Zahlungsverkehr heute keine Rolle mehr. Ich musste in einer kaufmännischen Ausbildung vor 25 Jahren noch alles lernen, was damit zu tun hat, auch das Wort '_Akzept_'. Wenn man häufiger ältere kaufmännische Texte liest, wird man früher oder später darauf stoßen - aber auch nur dann, so z.B. bei [Georg Weerth, Humoristische Skizzen aus dem deutschen Handelsleben](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/weerth/handel/handel01.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Während `Akzeptanz` *das* Substantiv für das Verb `akzeptieren` ist, gibt es rund um `Akzept` weitere Begriffe im Duden:

- Akzepta ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzepta))

  - Bedeutung: *Einnahmen*
- Akzeptant/in ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptantin))

  - Bedeutung: *Bankwesen: Annehmer, Bezogener eines Wechsels*
  - Bedeutung: *bildungssprachlich: Empfänger, Aufnehmender*
  - Herkunft: *lateinisch acceptans (Genitiv: acceptantis), 1. Partizip von: acceptare, akzeptieren*
- Akzeptkredit ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptkredit))

  - Bedeutung: *Wechselkredit*
- Akzeptor/in ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptorin))

  - Bedeutung: *Bankwesen: Annehmer, Empfänger [eines Wechsels]*
  - Bedeutung: *Chemie: Stoff oder Körper, der einen anderen bindet*
  - Herkunft: *lateinisch acceptor = Empfänger*

Zur Akzeptanz gehören vom engeren Wortsinn her diese Einträge:

- Akzeptabilitaet ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptabilitaet))

  - Bedeutung 1: *Annehmbarkeit*
  - Bedeutung 2: *von einem kompetenten Sprecher als sprachlich üblich und richtig beurteilte Beschaffenheit einer sprachlichen Äußerung*
  - Herkunft: *nach englisch acceptability*
  - Gebrauch: *Sprachwissenschaft*
- Akzeptierbarkeit ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptierbarkeit))

  - Bedeutung: *das Akzeptierbarsein*
- Akzeptierung ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptierung))

  - Bedeutung: *das Anerkennen, Einverstandensein mit etwas, jemandem*
- Akzeptivitaet ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akzeptivitaet))

  - Bedeutung: *Akzeptanz*

M.E. geht aus diese Worten im Duden rund um die Beschreibung, wie "etwas" von einem zum anderen kommt:

- das fiktive Geld in Form eines Wechsels
- die Idee/ Meinung in Form von Worten
- den Reaktionspartner auf chemischer Ebene

Somit gibt es als **Unterschied** spezifische Fachwörter (Akzepta) und "allgemeinen Wortschatz" (Akzeptanz) - die alle davon "reden", dass etwas angenommen = akzeptiert werden muss, um die Situation/ den Vorgang abzuschließen.

(Dass einige davon kaum genutzt werden, schließt deren Existenz nicht aus)